# Xamarin 5 and Mono 3 with GTK#, missing assemblies

Tags: c#, mono, xamarin, gtk, monodevelop

I have a problem with `Xamarin 5.7` and `Mono 3.12.0`, which should have also `GTK# 2.12.26`.

I made a `GTK#` project with the `Mono` runtime active and I disabled `MSBuild` in that project. I use .NET 4.

However, I can't compile it even with the template code, because the assemblies `atk-sharp`, `gdk-sharp`, `glade-sharp`, `glib-sharp`, `gtk-sharp` and `pango-sharp` are missing, but only when I compile using Mono.

With .NET 4.0 I don't have this problem, and the assemblies are loaded normally.

Also, I can't replace manually the libraries with the ones stored in `C:\Program Files (x86)\GtkSharp\2.12\lib\gtk-sharp-2.0`, because if I do it, the `Stetic GUI` editor becomes disabled.

So, how can I fix this hell of missing assemblies without manually replacing the references?

Comment: Why did you disable MSBuild engine?(future is with MSBuild engine, internal build system will probably be abandoned in future). Does it work with MSBuild engine enabled?

Comment: Actually, no. I can't compile by using MSBuild. It throws the "Unexpected binary element: 0". I can only compile by using XBuild.

Comment: Oh, now I understand... Well use .Net runtime(which is strongly recommended on Windows...) also MonoDevelop development on Windows is done with .Net runtime and not with Mono runtime...

Comment: Okay, I'll use .NET to build for Windows, but how about Mac and Linux? I really need to port my GTK# program to Mono, at least for these two platforms.

Also, I noticed that if I compile my GTK# project with .NET as default runtime, I get a missing assembly reference (`Mono.Posix`). Do I need to install GTK# for .NET too?

Comment: It seems like Mono.Posix is outdated in GTK# installer or not installed into .Net GAC(Not sure about this stuff)... I think it's best to use https://www.nuget.org/packages/Mono.Posix/. About cross platform... It doesn't matter what runtime you use on Windows you can still copy paste executables to Linux/Mac... But I still suggest you to compile on this systems just as sanity check... As I said MonoDevelop is using .Net on WIndows and there is no issues...